# Docker: unable to connect through https

Tags: docker, https, tls

I'm trying to get a docker container of Onlyoffice up and running.

I'm following the instructions provided on [GitHub](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/Docker-DocumentServer#running-onlyoffice-document-server-using-https), but get a connection refused error.

This is my docker command:

```
docker run -i -t -d -p 443:443 --restart=always -v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/logs:/var/log/onlyoffice -v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/data:/var/www/onlyoffice/Data -v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/lib:/var/lib/onlyoffice -v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/db:/var/lib/postgresql onlyoffice/documentserver
```

When I open the page in a browser, I got an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED message.

Using `lsof` I see docker has established a connection on port 443:

```
$lsof -i :443
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 2967 root    4u  IPv4 13839915      0t0  TCP 192.168.218.10:https (LISTEN)
```

What could possibly be wrong? When runnin on http (port 80) the docker image is working flawlessly.

Host Operating System:
Xubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Docker version:
Docker-ce 5.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround using a `reverse proxy`.

Most probably it will be some configuration specific for this server that prevents me from using docker on 443 (on a test server it works flawlessly).